# User control parameter in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I want to create a user control with a `bool` parameter that defines a dynamic behavior, using MVVM pattern, so I can use the user control in another view that way :

```
<local:MyUserControl BoolParam={Binding aBoolBinding} />
```

About the coding of the user control, the xaml should use the value of `BoolParam` to do something like this :

```
...
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{referenceToBoolParam}" Value="False" >
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
...
```

Am I supposed to define a property

`public bool BoolParam { get; set; }`

in the code-behind of the user control, and to code the logic associated to this parameter in the ViewModel of the user control ? 
Actually I am a bit confused about it, what is the good practice ?

Comment: read about dependecyProperties

Comment: yes, if I understand well the property will be dynamically updated if I declare it as a DependencyProperty in the code behind. But I am not sure it respects the MVVM pattern if I use the getter/setter do the dynamic work for the User Control ?

Comment: @SylvainB.In MVVM the "aBoolBinding" is located in a class in the ViewModel and "BoolParam" is a DependencyProperty of MyUserControl. For this to work the DataContext of MyUserControl should be the instance of the ViewModel class that contains the "aBoolBinding"

Comment: @SylvainB. so use Attached property insead, and make your dynamic work with setterGetter of userControl in it's viewModel.

Comment: @sTrenat & nkoniishvt : Sorry, I realized my question was not clear. I have done edits...

Comment: @SylvainB. It doens't change anything. You have two ways:
Make DependencyProperty in your UserControl, and bind to it with your textbox. Or make ViewModel for your UserControl, write there some properties like 'BoolParam', make attachedProperty to this in some extension class, and bind your textBox to your BoolParam. There is no other way. If you want your UserControl to be easy in use, you should leave MVVM for some moment and make write some DependencyProperties in code-behind.

Comment: Here there is nothing which breaks the MVVM. If you want to bind anything to view you need `dependency property`. MVVM says viewmodel should depend UI elements. Unless you are not using any UI elements you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BoolParam` should be a dependency property for you to be able to bind something to it. You define this in the code-behind of `MyUserControl`:

```
public bool BoolParam
{
    get { return (bool)this.GetValue(BoolParamProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(BoolParamProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BoolParamProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "BoolParam", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

You could then set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to an instance of a view model that contains a public `bool` property called `aBoolBinding` and bind to this one as usual.

**View Model:**

```
private bool _b;
public bool aBoolBinding
{
    get
    {
        return _b;
    }

    set
    {
        _b = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<local:MyUserControl BoolParam="{Binding aBoolBinding}" />
```

This is how data binding works. A target property in the views is bound to a source property of a view model.

**Edit:**

This binds to the `BoolParam` property of the `UserControl` from a `TextBox` style defined in the `UserControl`:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoolParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="False" >
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: In the end of this answer you explain how to bind "outside" the user control the bool. I am more looking for information on how to bind "inside" the user control the parameter `BoolParam` the `TextBox` visibility. The `BoolParam`has to be defined in the code behind, and the TextBox has to be bound to a property of the ViewModel... How to make both work together ?

Comment: Do you want to bind the TextBox in the UC to the BoolParam of the UC?

Comment: See my edited answer for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks !